# Not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, navigation-drawer, abstract

Hi everyone I have this Main Class Home

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, FriendsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

> Error:(42, 8) error: Home is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFragmentInteraction(String) in OnFragmentInteractionListener

I created a Navigation Drawer, and want to have a new Fragment to show another Content then on the Home Activity.

Android Studio tells me to make the home.class abstract or to implement an abstract method.

Inside here:

```
 public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public abstract void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
}
```

I did that but nothing changed. And I cant make the home class abstract because then its not starting the app anymore.

```
can't instantiate class com.myup2.up2.Home
```

**Edit 1:**
To call the Fragment I think I implemented the call correctly.

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransac = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch(position) {
        case 0:

            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
            newFragment = new FriendsFragment();
            break;
    }
    if(newFragment != null) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
                .commit();

    }
}
```

Thanks for reading in advanced and helping.

Comment: "want to have a new Fragment to show another Content then on the Home Activity" explain this. Are you saying that you want to switch from 1 fragment to another (that interface makes me think so) ?

Comment: I have my mainscreen (Main Activity) and want to go to my settings (Fragment) for example, through the navigation drawer.

Comment: Where are you facing a problem. Your code for showing the fragment is correct.

Comment: Error:(42, 8) error: Home is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFragmentInteraction(String) in OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: Dude you have to override that method in your activity. You have implemented it but have not overriden the method

Comment: Which thing do I need to override?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your activity :

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(PUT PARAMETERS HERE IF ANY) {
//do something here, maybe switch to another fragment
}
```

Comment: great :)
Tell me 1 thing, without this, do you not see a red underline where you have implemented the interfaces ? (the extends, implements line)

Comment: I haven't implemented the interface. Forgot that or something.